# Sorting horizontal stacked bar using d3js

Tags: d3.js

Am having an horizontal stacked bar chart using D3js which needs to be sorted,I have tried to implement the same using mbostock’s block #3886208 , but am getting NaN error. Am unable to parse the data within the sort function.
Please find my code at fiddle:

```
 http://jsbin.com/qovageconi/1/edit
```

Comment: Finally figured out the sorting function for the above graph by myself.
Please find the updated jsbin link.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/legicoxigu/1/edit?html,output           -> updated link